# How can I map a domain directly to an Azure storage blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

So, I can do this in AWS and I'm curious if it's possible in Azure blob storage.

Currently I've mapped a domain like so:
www.contoso.com -> http://asdf.blob.core.windows.net/

asdf has a container called 'main'. which contains my index.html, js, and .css files

Currently to hit the site I need to go to a url like this:
www.contoso.com/main/index.html

But what I really want is for people to be able to reach the files with just the .com address

Does anyone know if this is possible in azure?

Comment: I've never seen that feature in Azure Blob Storage documentation.

Comment: Can it be done using an HTTP redirect at the DNS level? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860481/how-do-i-set-up-dns-to-do-an-http-redirect-to-a-file-location-in-my-site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can store all of your static assets in Azure blobs, Azure doesn't have the notion of a *default* file in blob storage. That is, you cannot map your domain name to `index.html` for example. You can, however, reference all other static content directly e.g. `mysite.com/foo.html` (since `foo.html` would effectively be a blob).

You'd need a way to host your root file though. Where you place that is really up to you (e.g. web app, VM, cloud service). Since it's static content, web app might provide the best starting point (given there's a free tier, vs consuming an entire VM to host just a single file).

Comment: thanks, looks like I just need to use AWS s3 until azure adds this feature.  thank you!

Comment: Planned for the coming year https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/6417741-static-website-hosting-in-azure-blob-storage

Answer (score 2):

If google took you here, since June 2018, Azure blob storage introduced a new feature [static website](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-storage-static-web-hosting-public-preview/.)

And [this article](https://medium.com/@philippbauknecht/best-way-to-host-a-single-page-application-spa-in-microsoft-azure-3e70cbd075c3) should get you started.

PS. The performance data in the article above looks strange around Azure functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root container would solve your problem:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/working-with-the-root-container
Simply create a container called '$root', and then you can address blobs without referring to the container; e.g, www.contoso.com/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work, as Azure doesn't provide the notion of a "default" blob as a URL target (regardless of container).

Comment: this is very helpful Larry, unfortunately David is right about me nto being able to host a site this way.  As far as I can tell anyway.

Comment: There is a work around posted here https://blog.lifeishao.com/2017/05/24/serving-your-static-sites-with-azure-blob-and-cdn